# Jolt replace text using regex

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to transform an input data where I need to transform/replace the text on the basis of a regex. Not able to find any examples on how this can be done in Jolt spec. Could someone please help on this. Thanks!

Input

```
[
  {
    "name": "abc_google@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "ayan.agrawal$1990@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

Regex to be used

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9#$@]
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "abcgoogle@gmailcom"
  },
  {
    "name": "ayanagrawal$1990@gmailcom"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do in the way of doing with a regex. Need to think on the contrary manner, eg. rendering individually by each character to be removed, and we can do it by successively applying **split** and **join** functions such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "nm0": "=split('\\.',@(1,name))",
        "nm1": "=join('',@(1,nm0))",
        "nm2": "=split('_',@(1,nm1))",
        "name": "=join('',@(1,nm2))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "nm*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So it means there is no way of evaluating regular expressions in Jolt spec transformation by providing regex.

Comment: @ayan_2587 Yes , exactly.

Comment: Hi Barbaros.. Can you please help me with this query. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76630735/jolt-concatenate-two-strings-only-if-both-are-not-null